# Redirect rules in S3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created a bucket to host a static site and a redirect rule to redirect to a lambda function if the requested file doesn't exist

```
    {
        "Condition": {
            "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "xxx.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "307",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "write?file="
        }
    }
]
```

testing this one S3 works as expected. it shows the file of redirect to my lambda function if file doesn't exist. but when I put cloudfront in front of the S3 bucket when I hit the same file that doesnt exist I don't get the redirection but I get **AccessDenied** error (not sure if this is coming from s3 or cloudfront) any ideas how to make cloudfront honor the S3 rules?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're using CloudFront for distribution, you don't want the S3 bucket to be configured for a static website because it's CloudFront that is accessing the bucket, not the end user.

What you probably want to use is a private S3 bucket with CloudFront and use CloudFront's edge [trigger functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html) for handling files/paths that don't exist.

[This AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/) discusses some of the options. I'd suggest either of the "REST API" options.

Comment: makes sense. I made the bucket private and created the rule for cloudfront to access it. then I created a new origin with the lambda function (api gateway) I assume that cloudfront tries first to gt file from SE then it serves whatever the second origin returns right? because Im still getting the access denied error.

Comment: actually I dont need a new origin I can use the same origin and assign a lambda to the origin response trigger (not api gateway right?)

Comment: I'm not referring to using a Lambda as an origin, I'm talking about using a Lambda@Edge for the `Origin Response` trigger (see the link I included in my answer). Basically, it's a Lambda that runs whenever a response is returned from the origin (in this case, S3). You would check the response from S3, and if it's a 404, direct them somewhere else. [More documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-updating-http-responses.html).

Comment: yeah I sent a 2nd message with that. I tired doing what you suggested but I get "The maximum compressed size of your Lambda function cannot exceed 1 MB for viewer events.
Your function's execution role must be assumable by the edgelambda.amazonaws.com service principal. my function is bigger than 1mb :(

Comment: You have a function that just redirects to a new file, and it's > 1 MB? There seems like a larger design issue at play here.

Comment: it's a function that makes an http call to an image then resize it (using sharp) and then stores it in an S3 bucket so yes it's more than 1mb because it includes the node_modules folder with the dependencies. any other alternatives to  invoke a lambda function if the file doesnt existe in cloudfront > s3 ?

Comment: The only other options are to (1) create another Lambda that does this image processing, then invoke it synchronously from the Origin Response Lambda@Edge, wait for it to complete, then return a path to the newly created image in S3, or (2) use a CloudFront Custom Origin to point to an API Gateway deployment that uses a Lambda to serve the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235243/discussion-between-handsome-and-jordan).